# JAXB is adding unwanted attributes?

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb

I am serializing my Java model to `ATOM` using `JAXB`. For the title property that is of type Object (I can't change this to a `String`) it is adding namespace attributes.

```
<atom:title xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">
 myTitle
</atom:title>
```

this should be:

```
<atom:title>myTitle</atom:title>
```

Comment: Please show your annotated class...It is difficult to determine what is going on if all you provide is the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the `title` property to be of type `String`, then you can use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify the type of the property (as far as JAXB is concerned):

```
@XmlElement(namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", type=String.class)
public Object getTitle() {
    return title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't do that because `title` can either be a `String` or a `Title` object.

Comment: Do you know where those attributes are coming from?

Comment: @user86834 - The `xsi:type` attribute is being used to qualify the value that was set on the element.  In your sample document it is clear that you specified the `title` property with an instance of `String`.  The `xmlns:xsi` and `xmlns:xs` attributes are there to define the namespaces that were referenced by `xsi:type="xs:string"`.

Comment: Why are they being added automatically, my other `String` properties do not have them

Comment: @user86834 - They wouldn't be added to a property of type `String` holding a `String` because the types match.